# How to separate different environment block in application.yml in Micronaut

Tags: micronaut

In Grails, in `application.yml` there is a block `environment:` in which we can config same properties by different environment such as `developmenet`, `test`, and `production`. For example:

```
environments:
    development:
        logging:
            config: classpath:logback-dev.xml
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop  
            # url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
            driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
            url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/my_db
            username: 'user'
            password: 'user'
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    production:
        logging:
            config: classpath:logback-prod.xml
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: none
            url: jdbc:h2:./prodDb;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    ....
```

Can we do the same thing above in Micronaut application's `application.yml` ?

I know I can use VM options `-Dmicronaut.config.files as below for different servers(environments):

```
java -Dmicronaut.config.files=/etc/fooApp/application.yml -jar fooApp.jar
```

But I prefer to use Grails' approach because with that way I just need to maintain one config file.

Answer (score 1):

You can define different YAML files. A file for each environment such as `application.yml` for prod, `application-test.yml` for test and `application-yolo.yml` for environment yolo.

The key thing is that you usually define all the keys for the productive environment in the `application.yml`. For the other environments you can overwrite dedicated keys.

Given the following `application.yml` for production

```yaml
micronaut:
   server:
     port: 3000

some:
   other:
     config: ABC
```

and you maybe want to overwrite the `some.other.config` value for the test environment you can simply create the following `application-test.yml`.

```yaml
some:
   other:
     config: XYZ
```

The nice thing about it is, that this configuration does not affect the `micronaut.server.port` which means you don‘t have to duplicate your configuration for each environment.

If you want to run the application with the `test` (or any other environment) activated you simply tell Micronaut the environment names instead of referring to a configuration file.

```bash
java -Dmicronaut.environments=test -jar myapp.jar
```